# What would the seasonal patterns be like on this world?

Tags: hard-science, climate, axial-tilt

Here's the set up on this system I have:  The sun is .99 solar mass, .97 luminosity.  The world in question has the following orbital parameters:

- Dist: 1.253 AU Orbital Period: 1.41 (rel. to Earth)
- Radius: 7190 km
- 1.705 Earth mass
- Eccentricity: .0095
- Obliquity: 21.3 degrees

(I know, so far you're thinking, "Cold Earth"...but wait for it)

It has a moon with the following parameters:

- Dist. from planet: 1,473,950 km
- Orbital period: 152.5998 days
- Rotational Period: 22 hrs. (Due to its distance, this moon is not tidally locked. I checked using a tidal-locking spreadsheet)
- Radius: 3860 km, .1839 Earth mass
- No Eccentricity (or so slight to be negligible)
- Obliquity: 16.3
- Orbital Inclination 4.2
- Atmospheric density: .554 Earth's
- 22.3% hydrosphere
- Albedo: approx. .2289

I'm trying to get it positioned to maximize the warmth on this world, much like the way Triton is orbiting Neptune so that its orbital inclination, axial tilt and the axial tilt of the primary all enhance each other.  But I was curious, due to its wide orbit, would this world experience multiple summers and winters?  Would the seasons cancel each other out, or would they make them more extreme?

I know it seems like a rather tall order, but thanks in advance!

-M-

Comment: Have you checked that the moon is within the planet's [Hill Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere)? That looks a bit marginal to me, although I have not done the calculations. If it is not, then it won't stay with the planet for very long, on astronomical timescales.

Comment: That moon is well within the planet's Hill Sphere. Planet's hill sphere extends 2.21million km, moon is at 1.47million. (it helps that the planet is in a wider orbit than Earth)

Comment: Um. some number crunching later. Why do you feel the moon will affect seasons? It doesn't affect planet inclination in short term. Full moon light is very similar to Earth fullmoon only, so no heat there. And during fullmoon the planet is only 287000km closer to the sun than at newmoon, so solar illumination varies less than 0.38%, not enough to make a difference.

Comment: I'm not asking about the planet's seasons...those will be rather straightforward; earthlike, but cooler (possibly...once I factor in albedo and greenhouse it might look different).  Rather, the question is about the moon itself.

Comment: @Mike Could you please clarify your question then?

Comment: I was asking about what the seasons might be like on the moon, which orbits far from its planet.  It has a mass of .18 earths, so is able to retain an atmosphere. Because of its orbit, it has a non-synchronous rotation. I have since figured this one out:  the seasons will be weirdly complex (basically a "hot" and "cold" version of each season.)  Thanks to all who tried.

Comment: You know **Mike** if you figured out an solution your self you could always answer your own question. Who knows maybe it would help others if you shared your knowledge. Though it is just a suggestion of course you are free to decide what you will do with this question.